# How to get the file name extension in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am receiving an array, which I am using in `ng-repeat` in AngularJS. In that array there are some file names like  `abc.pdf`, `xyz.jpg`, `test.png`

Now from these file names I want to **get the extension** of those files. How to do it in AngularJS / HTML?

Comment: Do you want to show these extensions or store in some variable?

Comment: using `lastIndexOf` is key here while performing any operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use javascript substring method:

```
fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.')+1)
```

If you want to use it in html directly i would suggest you to create a filter based on the above logic.

```
angular.module('App.filters', [])
    .filter('ext', [function () {
        return function (text) {
            return text.split('.').pop();
        };
    }]);
```

And you can use it in templates as:

```
{{filename | ext}}
```

Comment: why not just `split`? `"abc.pdf".split(".")[1]`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey A file name can have dots inside the name itself... Eg. foo.tar.gz, bar.user.js, etc.  
You can still use split and get the last item of the array, but it becomes as complex (if not more) than the given solution.
And creating an array of strings just for that isn't very efficient (very minor point, though).

Comment: Again if you want to use split.. you can use fileName.split(".").pop() which will return the last element of the array but again creating string array would not be much efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Convert(map) the array before rendering it e.g.

```
var fileNames = ['abc.pdf', 'xyz.jpg']
$scope.files = fileNames.map(function (fileName) {
  return {
    name: fileName,
    ext: fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)
  }
});
```

Then render

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="file in files">{{file.name}} {{file.ext}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use simple Javascript:

```
array.map(elem => elem.substring(elem.indexOf('.') + 1)
```

This will return new array of file extension for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
"abc.pdf".split(".")[{Index Of Last Element}]
```

which in most cases would be

```
abc.pdf".split('.')["abc.pdf".split('.').length -1];
```

This should do the trick.